# How to setup Master-Master replication in Windows using MySQL

Tags: mysql, windows

I have checked on various websites, but all of them give different steps.

Comment: Please provide details of the research you've done.

Comment: https://www.ryadel.com/en/mysql-master-master-replication-setup-in-5-easy-steps/

I am following the steps on this website, but I am unable to connect one master to another.

error connecting to master 'replicator@ip_address' - retry-time: 60  retries: 16